# Guard Method for Integer C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, if-statement, integer

I'm trying to check if a parameter that was received is 0, but as I'm doing this alot I would like to have a faster way to check if it is 0 and not to have to do an entire if check every time.

Exactly like the Guard method allow me to do that with string.
This Guard method: using CommunityToolkit.Diagnostics;

Here's an example code:

```
 Guard.IsNotNullOrEmpty(myname);
 Guard.IsNotNullOrEmpty(yourname);

 //this works for strings and if that string is null or empty it will generate an Execption for me

 if(myage == 0 )
             {
                 throw new Exception("Your age cannot be 0");
             }

 //this does check if myage is 0, but it took 3 lines of code`


There is something like Guard for integers?
```

Comment: "Exactly like the Guard method allow me to do that with string." What Guard method are you talking about? Perhaps this is something in a library you're using?

Comment: You could write your own static method to do this....

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, i'm using the CommunityToolkit.Diagnostics library.

Comment: @Slappywag Yes, I could. But I'm trying to find something that is already in a library or ready to use. If this does not exists, than yes, I'll create it

Comment: Right, it looks like you should be able to use `Guard.IsGreaterThan` in that case, or `Guard.IsNotEqualTo` if you *really* want to allow negative ages. Note that `Guard` isn't a method, it's a class.

Answer (score 2):

checkout this repo: https://github.com/Revazashvili/Forbid, there is bunch of methods you can use.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this project which you can get on nuget also:
https://github.com/safakgur/guard

it encompasses multi requirement in one line, plus logging.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Guard.IsNotDefault`([source](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/blob/main/CommunityToolkit.Diagnostics/Guard.Comparable.Generic.cs)):

```
Guard.IsNotDefault(myage);
```